# Using weights in prognostic models of Survival Analysis data

Tags: survival, treatment-effect, weighted-data, competing-risks

I have a dataset where I'm comparing Survival (overall and cancer-specific survival) between two treatment groups (Surgery vs. Radiation) for prostate cancer. As suggested by Noordzij et al (PMID
23975843). I will be using this guide for choosing methodology:

***NO Competing risks***

1. Prognostic research question (i.e.Calculation of Survival probability)
   a.  Unadjusted: Kaplan Meir method
   b.  Adjusted: Multivariate Cox regression
2. Aetiological  research question: Estimation of Treatment effect (Hazard Ratio )
   a.  Unadjusted: Univariate Cox regression
   b.  Adjusted: Multivariate Cox regression

****Competing risks** *Present***

3. Prognostic research question (Calculation of Survival probability)
   a. Unadjusted:  Cumulative incidence competing risks method (CICR)
   b. Adjusted: Sub-distribution Hazards (Fine & Gray) method
4. Aetiological  research question: Estimation of Treatment effect (Hazard Ratio )
   a.  Unadjusted: Univariate cause-specific proportional hazards model
   b.  Adjusted: Multivariate cause-specific proportional hazards model
   •   * 4a and 4b done using standard cox-regression, but with censoring of the competing event

As the treatment groups are non-randomised, I will be using IPTW (inverse probability of treatment weighting) to derive propensity scores and create a weighted, balanced dataset.

MY QUERY: I will be using the IPTW-weighted dataset for 4a and 4b above ( i.e etiological question) but shouldn't I be using the **weighted** dataset for the Survival probability (prognostic question) too? In other words, I could do a crude dataset K-M curve analysis, but isn't it better if done on the weighted dataset? Similarly, should I be doing a crude dataset Competing risks analysis or one where the IPTW weights are applied (weighted Fine and Grey)?

THANK YOU SO MUCH, WONDERFUL FRIENDS

P.s: Medical Doctor here, no statistical experience doing this myself :(.